# Possible transmission fluid leak

Tags: toyota, transmission, automatic-transmission, leak

2001 Toyota 4Runner SR5 265K miles.

I haven't driven it in 2 days and came out and found a small pool (about 2 teaspoons at the most) underneath the engine area. It's clear with a tinge of red, no scent, slightly oily in texture. I've checked my fluids, which seem normal. If anything my coolant *might* be a little lower than the last time I checked. The tranny fluid seems normal. When I popped my head underneath (see pictures) I identified the leak coming from the transmission area. I'm not that familiar with engine components, sorry. Anyway, you can see the leak I'm talking about in the second picture below (the silver circular piece in the middle of the shot). Is this transmission fluid that I'm seeing? I was going to take it in to be looked at tomorrow, but I'm curious in the meantime.

Thanks.

**UPDATE**: I had a mechanically-inclined friend look over the area and he couldn't find anything significant. In fact, I haven't seen anything dripping from the area in 2 days. He (maybe incorrectly) suggested that perhaps the extreme cold weather (for California...near freezing) which set in very quickly coupled with the fact that I hadn't driven it in a few days (around 4) may be the reason for the dripping. My transmission fluid level was within normal limits and he told me just to keep an eye out for any more dripping and potentially take it in if it occurs. Is there any other contradictory advice or support from the community?

[image: Skid plate (I'm directly under the driver side looking forward)]

[image: Transmission(?) directly above front axle]